# Alamofire responseDecodable for model for response and error

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm using Alamofire to make API calls from mobile app. I have struct which is map from Alamofire API calls this way

```
APIManager.shared.session.request(UserRouter.signUp(username, password)).responseDecodable (of: User.self) { response in
  complition(response.value, response.error)
}
```

When API call is failed and returned API error is JSON format I'm getting `AFError`

```
▿ Optional<AFError>
  ▿ some : AFError
    ▿ responseSerializationFailed : 1 element
      ▿ reason : ResponseSerializationFailureReason
        ▿ decodingFailed : 1 element
          ▿ error : DecodingError
            ▿ keyNotFound : 2 elements
              - .0 : ContainerKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil)
              ▿ .1 : Context
                - codingPath : 0 elements
                - debugDescription : "Cannot get KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys> -- no value found for key ContainerKeys(stringValue: \"user\", intValue: nil) (\"user\")"
                - underlyingError : nil
```

This is what API returning back on that call

```
{
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    "Email can't be blank",
    "Password can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

I end up writing this to get it handle:

```
struct APIError: Error, Decodable {
    var success: Bool
    var errors: [String]
}
```

```
    APIManager.shared.session.request(UserRouter.signUp(username, password)).responseDecodable (of: User.self) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            complition(value, nil)
        case .failure:
            let somethingWrong = APIError(success: false, errors: ["Something went wrong. Please try again."])

            guard let data = response.data else {
                complition(nil, somethingWrong)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let error = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
                complition(nil, error)
            } catch {
                complition(nil, somethingWrong)
            }

        }
    }
```

How this code can be written better way, maybe Alamofire does support map error model
as well.

Comment: Why you are trying to Decode the data when the request fails? The problem occurs because you are trying to decode data with ```APIError``` model where there is no key named ```user```.

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution here is to use an enum as your base response type.

```swift
enum APIResult<Success: Decodable> {
  case success(Success)
  case failure(APIError)
}
```

You can then either make the enum directly conform to `Decodable` (there are many solutions out there for that), or create your own Alamofire `ResponseSerializer` which handles the decoding logic for you. That approach is more work but is more flexible, as you can consider the request and response when parsing.